# Facebook likes to android app

Tags: java, android, facebook

Can anybody know how to get the facebook likes to an android app..
I have an android app and I have a Facebook page also.. I need to display the updated likes of my facebook page to android app... Is it possible

Comment: yes possible one of my app am integrated facebook like option.

Comment: To some extent, everything is possible. Have you tried something? Do you have any problems?

Comment: I didn't try.. I know it is possible to connect Facebook.. but displaying facebook likes ..I dont know... if it is possible .. I can start work on t..